# When there are two identical smallest values in a list, how do you get the first value instead of the second?

Tags: python, list

I have to get the smallest value from a list of monthly precipitation stats, then find the index of that element, then get the element with the same index value from a dictionary. This is the part of the code that is supposed to do this:

```
# finds the minimum precipitation from user's inputs and finds the corresponding month
min_precipitation = min(precipitation_by_month)
lowest_precipitation = precipitation_by_month.index(min_precipitation)
lowest_precipitation_month = months.pop(lowest_precipitation)
print (lowest_precipitation_month, 'has the lowest precipitation:', "{:.2f}".format(min_precipitation), 'inches.')
```

The problem is that in one of the inputs for this HW there are two 0.00 values in the list, but the program gets the second 0.00 value instead of the first (which is required) and therefore the wrong index number too.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not reproducible, the program *never* gets the second value. `min` is stable (like Python sorting in general), and always returns the first copy of equal values. Even if it didn't, the `.index` call works from left to right and stops when it gets a hit, so you'd always pop out the first of the two values. So either this isn't your real code ([MCVE] that aren't actually reproducing the problem are useless), or your inputs aren't what you claim they are (are they actually two numbers that aren't *quite* zero, and the second is legit smaller?).

Comment: You can verify stability pretty easily thanks to the existence of `-0.0`; `-0.0 == 0.0` is true, and `min([-0.0, 0.0])` always produces `-0.0` (because it appears first), while `min([0.0, -0.0])` always gets `0.0` (again, it appears first).

Comment: @pythonoob What makes you say "the program gets the second 0.00 value instead of the first"? Can you provide example inputs and outputs?

Comment: If you're using floats, have you checked for floating-point errors? Your output formatting will hide small differences.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `list.index` method with the `min(list)` method and you will get index of the first smallest number in the list:

```
n = [0,1,2,3,0]

print(n.index(min(n)))
```

Output:

```
Index is: 0
```